range without the preposition "to"
I wonder how or why it is possible to use the verb "range" with the preposition "from" but without "to". This is one of the examples that I have encountered:

this ranges from the basis on which funds are provided to the real sector, the ways in which the ownership of equity by financial corporations impacts on the behavior of non-financial corporations and the degree to which non-financial corporations themselves engage in financial operations.


It's obviously possible, since you've found someone who wrote it. But that sentence is very poorly written. Don't copy it. You haven't even reproduced the entire sentence above. in full, it's...

Where did you encounter this example?

It is also relevant to discuss how the interaction between the financial sector and the real sector has changed: this ranges from the basis on which funds are provided to the real sector, the ways in which the ownership of equity by financial corporations impacts on the behaviour of non-financial corporations and the degree to which non-financial corporations themselves engage in financial operations.

...It's English, Jim. But not as we know it.

The why is simply because in such a clunky tortuous "sentence" (which already uses the word to three times) we probably wouldn't notice an extra instance of that word anyway. And the writer himself probably forgot where he was going with that text.

Basically, they misused the phrase "ranges from", since what they're referring to is a list of things, not a continuum with a start and end.

Intransitive 'range' may use 'over' / 'across', but (except perhaps in rare examples like 'ranged far and wide from Britain')  with 'from' needs 'to' and with 'between' needs 'and'.

It's a typo, obscured by the fact that the author's writing style makes the whole thing nearly unreadable even without this error.

@FumbleFingers has it. Even helpful grammar checkers may have accepted the "from-to" pair as satisfied. And yet. The list needed "From A, to B, to C."

@YosefBaskin: I can't help noticing you included an "Oxford comma" in your list, where it's completely unnecessary as an aid to the reader (it's only real purpose). But with OP's cited text (assuming and the degree... is indeed the final item in a list of three, not just another thing "impacted upon"), that comma really ought to be included as a matter of courtesy.

Yes, my Oxford comma applied to the big sentence.

It's possible with certain meanings of range.
From Merriam-Webster,

1 a : to roam at large or freely
b : to move over an area so as to
explore it

as in

In contrast to the Little Swift it is not gregarious but occurs in
scattered pairs; these are tied to nesting sites from which they range
widely during the day but return to roost at night. (Waterberg)

or

5 : to change or differ within limits

as in

His music features the asymmetric
rhythms and modal harmonies typical of his homeland
but, like Béla Bartók, Ourkouzounov (pronounced
Oor-koo-ZOO-nov) uses regional traditions as a point
of departure from which he ranges widely in an intuitive and personal way. (NYC Classical Guitar Society)


I don't think either of these definitions corresponds to the way the word is used in the given text. It's using the definition corresponding to "range from X to Y", except it's "range from X, Y, and Z"

Thank you so much for all the comments—especially @DW256. I stated in my question that this is one of the examples that I encountered. The other one was from Collins dictionary: to extend, run, or go in a certain direction
a boundary ranging from east and west. But I had (and still has :) some difficulty comprehending the usage.

Also << range [verb] [intransitive] to stretch out or extend in a line, as things:
shabby houses ranged along the road. [Dictionary.com] >> Thus 'small settlements ranged along the highway from less than a mile outside the city limits'.

What you're quoting is poorly written.

this springs from the basis on which funds are provided to the real sector...

...is closer to what the author should have written. If you begin a phrase with "...ranges from" you most likely need a "to" in there, too.

Or 'results'. It's one possibility. But OP asks about the behaviour of the highly polysemous verb 'range'.

"Results from the basis..." Nah.
